# Validity of the Java Code

Tags: java, operators

```
double ABC = - UTIL_COMMON.fnChkDouble(lStr);
```

Above statement, is it valid or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's valid as long as the operator `-` can be applied to the return type of `UTIL_COMMON.fnChkDouble()`. As you want to assign a double, this method most probably returns a double, so this is **valid** code.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to say without seeing the declaration of `lstr` and the method signature of `fnChkDouble`.